# Dynamically center blocks on page resize?

Tags: html, css, centering

I want these blocks to always be centered in the page no matter what the screen dimension is.

http://seriouslyineedthis.com/

The problem is that it always floats to the left.

*I was using the Masonry plugin, but had issues with overlapping (so I don't want that to be an answer).

In the code I'm simply doing this:

```
<div id="content_holder_outside">
<div id="content_holder">
     <!-- Blocks and content go here -->
</div>
</div>

#content_holder_outside {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    }

#content_holder {
    min-height:600px;
    }
```

It's super simple, but that's not working. Everything's still floated to the left. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it works fine on chrome.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Minimise your browser.

Comment: By "minimize" he means make the viewport width smaller

Comment: Yes, It looks good with a max width of 1280px and up. But as you make the browser width smaller, the blocks float left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `display: inline-block;` to your `#each_box_holder` and remove `float:left` from it, it will stay centered.

Note: change it from `id` to `class`. An `id` should be used only when it is **unique**. In your case it is not, so using a `class` is better and will save you a lot of trouble in the feature.

Comment: I did all of that, but it still doesn't work. You can check the source to see the changes.

Comment: I am looking at your source and you didn't change it. It still has `float:left` on the `#each_box_holder`

Comment: I didn't said to add `display:inline-block` to `.content_holder`... read closer. Btw, I cleared cache and refreshed. You didn't do what I said there.

Comment: My fault, I was changing .content_holder_outside. Perfect it works! Thanks a lot!